# Next.js: Persist state with Context API and localStorage

Tags: next.js, react-hooks, local-storage, next.js13, react-context

I'm fairly new to Next.js and trying to store a boolean value in localStorage to be accessible in multiple components and between page reloads. Basically, I'm trying to implement a simple feature toggle, that can be toggle using a button and which state will persist.

I'm using:

```
"next": "^13.5.4",
"react": "^18.2.0",
```

Currently, I'm receiving the error:

> Text content did not match. Server: "false" Client: "true"

```
// src/app/page.tsx

import { UITweakingProvider } from '@here/context/UIToggleContext';

const SearchPage: React.FC = () => {

return (
  <UITweakingProvider>
    // components
  </UITweakingProvider>
)
```

===

```
// src/context/UIToggleContext.tsx

'use client';

import useLocalStorage from "@here/hooks/useLocalStorage/useLocalStorage";
import { Dispatch, PropsWithChildren, SetStateAction, createContext, useContext } from "react";

type ContextType = {
    UITweaking: boolean;
    setUITweaking: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}

const initialState: ContextType = {
    UITweaking: false,
    setUITweaking: (status: SetStateAction<boolean>): void => {},
};

const UITweakingContext = createContext<ContextType>(initialState);

function useUITweakingContext(): ContextType {
    return useContext(UITweakingContext);
}

function useUITweakingToggle() {
    return useLocalStorage<boolean>('displayUITweaking', false)
}

function UITweakingProvider({ children }: PropsWithChildren) {
    const [UITweaking, setUITweaking] = useUITweakingToggle();

    return (
        <UITweakingContext.Provider value={{UITweaking, setUITweaking}}>
                {children}
        </UITweakingContext.Provider>
    );
}

export default UITweakingContext;
export { UITweakingProvider, useUITweakingContext };
```

===

```
// src/hooks/useLocalStorage/useLocalStorage.ts

import { APP_PREFIX } from '@here/config/constants/constants';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function useLocalStorage<T>(key: string, fallbackValue: T) {
    const keyValue = APP_PREFIX + key;
    const [value, setValue] = useState<T>(() => {
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
            const storedValue = localStorage.getItem(keyValue);
            return storedValue ? JSON.parse(storedValue) : fallbackValue;
        }
        return fallbackValue;
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem(keyValue, JSON.stringify(value));
    }, [key, value]);

    return [value, setValue] as const;
}
```

===

Here is the component where I tried to use render the value provided by context and change it.

```
// src/components/TweakUIToggle/TweakUIToggle.tsx

import { useUITweakingContext } from "@here/context/UIToggleContext";
import { UIToggleButton } from "./TweakUIToggle.styles";

const TweakUIToggle: React.FC = () => {
    const { UITweaking, setUITweaking} = useUITweakingContext();

    const toggleUITweaking = () => {
        setUITweaking((prevValue) => !prevValue)
    }

    return <UIToggleButton onClick={toggleUITweaking}>Toggle UI Tweaking {UITweaking.toString()}</UIToggleButton>
}

export default TweakUIToggle;
```

It works fine, until I reload the page to check if my hook retrieves data from localStorage. Hook's initial state gets reset to false/initial value, and I get the error: Text content did not match. Server: "false" Client: "true"

Also, it works if I import my final component like that:

```
const TweakUIToggle = dynamic(() => import("@here/components/TweakUIToggle/TweakUIToggle"), { ssr: false });
```

However, it looks weird to me and I'm not sure if developers do that in real projects in case of functionality like mine.

I've been battling it for the last 5 hours, looked through multiple resources, but still miss the idea of what should be done. I would appreciate any help, thank you!